# comparison of speed and memory

Tags: c++, performance, memory

I have billions of lables. These lables contain about at most 20 integers ranging from 1 to 500. I need to search for the existence of each integer in each lable and maybe insert the integer to the lable. I have memory limit too. So I need to delete the lables in some cases to free up memory. 
which one is better?
using vector for saving the data of lables or using unordered_set?

Comment: Showing some code of your data structures (or part of it) might help

Comment: Does the order of those integers matter? If no, `std::bitset` may be an answer, as it needs only around 500 bits for each of your labels and capable of adding/checking each integer at `O(1)` for each label.

Comment: let think about 2 possible cases. 1) the order dose not matter and no duplicate member is allowed 2) we can have repetition and also order matters.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It is not clear how vector and unordered_set are alternatives, when you have many labels and each contains many integers

Comment: btw the only way to answer this question is to try out both ways and to compare them

Comment: sorry lable is just  the name of an object  in my code.

Comment: I'd say that won't fit in memory. Have you thought of using a DB?

Comment: if you want to test only existance of number, how does order can matters ? What other purpose these data will have ?

Answer (score 1):

as already hinted in one of the comments:

`std::bitset` will take less space than the 20 integers and gives `O(1)` add/check. this is a good idea, if you have on average more than 15 values per label or can live with some extra memory usage.

if not, i'd recommend vector over set.

- it is aligned in memory (less cache misses => faster)
- it has smaller memory footprint
- if you have bulk insert, you can `reserve()`
- if your vector is sorted, you can use `std::binary_search` to have `O(log n)` lookup

As a rule of thumb: if you have less than 50 elements, vector is your container of choice.

As far as i got you, the critical operation is to find all labels, that contain a certain vaue?

- Did you consider flipping the structure? Instead of storing ints in
  each label, why not have a list of references to labels for each of
  your 500 values?
- Did you consider a (no-sql) DB to get rid of the memory constraints?